# JavaScript: Getting rid of three JSHint errors

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, jshint

Please find below a snippet of my Node.JS server code:

```
// Define the user API
var API = {
    list: 'private',
    login: 'public',
    logout: 'private',
    add: 'admin',
    remove: 'admin',
    edit: 'admin'
};

// Attach API handlers
for(var label in API) {
    var denied = 'Permission denied';

    var wrapper = (function (label) {
        return function (req, res) {
            var permission = API[label];

            if(!req.session) {
                if(permission !== 'public') {
                    res.send(denied);
                    return;
                }
            } else if((permission === 'admin') && (req.session.rights !== 'Administrator')) {
                res.send(denied);
                return;
            }

            eval(label + '(req, res)');
        };
    }(label));

    server.post('/user/' + label, wrapper);
}
```

Basically, I have an API handler for each property in `API`, and I attach the handlers programmatically, dealing with permissions as appropriate. JSHint however really does not like this. I get three errors:

```
Line 29: eval(label + '(req, res)');
eval is evil.

Line 31: }(label));
Don't make functions within a loop.

Line 12: for(var label in API) {
The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.
```

How can this piece of code be improved to make JSHint happy? Are there other changes you would suggest to the code?

Comment: if `label` is a function defined in the global scope you could do `window[label](req,res);`

Comment: Would appreciate a comment from the downvoter.

Comment: `The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.`  there you should check for API.hasOwnProperty(label)  if label is really a property you set or if it is inherited by the prototype chain.

Comment: There aren't always unwanted properties on the prototype chain, if you know this, then you don't need to use hasOwnProperty(), as it is a waste or resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend going through the options that make jslint less strict and setting these ( provided you understand the why ).  Jslint is very strict and that is why it has options to make it less strict.  The important thing is that you know why they were flagged and why it is OK ok for you to allow these things.

For example to allow eval use:

```
/*jslint evil: true */
```

Some use:

```
/*jslint plusplus: true */
```

as they find that ++ and -- cause them no problems with bug creation or readability.

jslint is used to bring attention to POTENTIAL pitfalls.  If you understand them, you can go around them.